# Return dictionary in __str__() python

Tags: python, class, dictionary, return

I am starting with classes and i got stuck at this: I want to print out a dictionary in `def __str__(self)` but when I use print it gives me an error and when I use return in prints only one line. Can you help me please?

```
class Contact(object):

    def __init__(self, name, phone, email):
        self.name = name
        self.phone = phone
        self.email = email

    def __str__(self):
        return "{} {} {}".format(self.name, self.phone, self.email)

class ContactList(object):

    def __init__(self, d={}):
        self.d = d

    def add_contact(self, n):
        self.d[n.name] = [n.phone, n.email]

    def del_contact(self, n):
        self.d[n] = 0
        del self.d[n]

    def get_contact(self, n):
        if n in self.d:
            return '{} {} {}'.format(n, self.d[n][0], self.d[n][1])
        else:
            return '{}: No such contact'.format(n)

    def __str__(self):
        print('Contact list')
        print('------------')
        for key in sorted(self.d.items()):
            print(Contact(key[0], key[1][0], key[1][1]))
```

The error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "contacts_72.py", line 58, in <module>
    main()
  File "contacts_72.py", line 51, in main
    print(cl)
TypeError: __str__ returned non-string (type NoneType)
```

Comment: It doesn't look to me like your returning any dictionaries...

Comment: Because __str__ is a function, not a procedure, so you have to return value to be displayed.

Comment: Do you want `"{}\n{}\n{}".format(...)` instead?

Comment: I want to return all entries in the dictionary but when i use return it only returns 1

Comment: Please add Traceback to your question.

Comment: @zondo yes something like that

Comment: Try it.  That should work.

Comment: it should but i have no idea how many entries are in the dictionary

Comment: @user3100115 added

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `__str__` of `ContactList` should return a string. You may try something like this.

```
def __str__(self):
    c_list = 'Contact list\n' + '------------\n'
    for key, value in sorted(self.d.items()):
        c_list += str(Contact(key, value[0], value[1]))
    return c_list
```

Update the `Contact` class `__str__` method with this. (just added newline char at the end.)

```
def __str__(self):
    return "{} {} {}\n".format(self.name, self.phone, self.email)
```

Comment: Oh man that's really close but is it possible to place one entry on each line?

Comment: Update the Contact class str method as the edited answer. (just added newline char at the end.)